# Installing an exe file -VBSCript

Tags: vbscript

I use the following command to run a exe file which is in the network drive through a vbscript:

```
wsh.Run """\\lonmsc01\apps$\EWebEditPro\Version 4\ewebeditproclient4.exe"""
```

This installation pops up with dialog boxes to choose the setup type As `Resintall` or `Remove` and proceeds on by clicking on `Next` to finish the set up.

Is there any way I could disable the `UI` and install it silently?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what setup utility was used. Mose installers have a silent or quiet operator. Try calling the setup with the parameter `/?`, it might tell which parameters you can pass him. Or you just try different switches, like `/silent`, `/quiet` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of using vbscript to silently install software is a bad idea.  User interaction or at least user notification should be involved in all software installations unless you're a network admin using an Enterprise management tool.  This struck me as sneaky, so I did a search for the exe you mentioned.

A quick google search indicates this ***may*** be malware you're trying to install... At least according to the Prevx site, it's listed as potential spyware.  You're not asking us for help in silently installing malware, are you?

At any rate, even if this is legit (which it probably is) it's a bad idea.  In today's world, silent installs should be completely disallowed.

http://spywarefiles.prevx.com/spywarefilesweek.asp?mk=43998135